# Json from JsonAction returning as HTML not firing callback function

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm trying to get a simple true/false json return from a JsonAction, but it keeps returning as html, not firing my $(post) callback function.
Here are the codes:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RegisterPartial(RegisterModel model)
{

    return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JQuery in .cshtml

```
$(function () {
        $('#RegisterPartial').live("submit", (function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (retorno) {
            if (retorno.Success) {
                alert('success');
                window.location(gup("returnUrl"));
            }
        }, "json");

    }))
});
```

here's response in browser (validated in jasonlint.com):

```
{"Success":false}
```

I also tried contentTypes "application/json" and Encoding.UTF8 but response is always an html page instead of firing the jquery callback function. Also tried $.ajax() but still same response.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what `#RegisterPartial` is. Is it a form? It should be as you are subscribing to the submit event. So this form should look like this:

```
@Html.BeginForm("RegisterPartial", "SomeController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "RegisterPartial" })
{
    ... some input elements

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Is this the case? Also you seem to have a javascript error (you have a trailing `)`) when closing the `.live()` anonymous function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#RegisterPartial').live("submit", (function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function (retorno) {
            if (retorno.Success) {
                alert('success');
                window.location(gup("returnUrl"));
            }
        }, "json");
    }); // <-- You've had a trailing ) here. 
    // Only one ) is necessary whereas you had 2
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Darin. In revising the code to check what you pointed out I found that I had changed the id of the form so my jquery code wasn't even been triggered. Now it's just fine.